# How to build json object from array in Postgresql

Tags: json, postgresql

I am trying to build a json object from a string.
My string is: the quick; lazy fox
I want to build a json object as below:

I try the sql script below
SELECT
json_build_object(
'value', string_to_array('the quick; lazy fox', ';'))
The result will be:

> {    "value":[
> "the quick",
> " lazy fox"    ] }

But i want to have the result below:

> {    "result":[
> {
> "value":"the quick"
> },
> {
> "value":"lazy fox"
> }    ] }

Can everyone give me a hand?

Comment: You'll need to `jsonb_agg`regate an array over a query `from unnest(string_to_array('the quick; lazy fox', ';'))`

Comment: Can you explain in detail or give me the sql script @Bergi

Answer (score 3):

Try this :

```
SELECT json_build_object( 'result', json_agg(json_build_object( 'value', c.content)))
FROM unnest(string_to_array('the quick; lazy fox', ';')) AS c(content)
```

Result :

```
{"result" : [{"value" : "the quick"}, {"value" : " lazy fox"}]}
```

Comment: it works, thanks for your help